# ¿Cómo hacer JSON tipo esquema usando JSON.net?

Tags: json, vb.net

Estoy haciendo un API REST en ASP utilizando Visual Basic como código base. Cabe recordar que no hay mucha documentacion para tal lenguaje al respecto.

Tengo este JSON:

```
{
   "Id": 1,
   "NombreUsuario": "admin",
   "Clave": "admin",
   "CorreoElectronico": "admin@localhost",
   "Token": "0m1sand5p2ru5gdinaewi2ox"
}
```

Pero lo que quiero es crear el objeto JSON de esta manera:

```
{
   "statusCode" : 200,
   "statusText" : "OK",
   "data" : [
      {
         "Id": 1,
         "NombreUsuario": "admin",
         "Clave": "admin",
         "CorreoElectronico": "admin@localhost",
         "Token": "0m1sand5p2ru5gdinaewi2ox"
      }
   ]
}
```

No encuentro la manera de ingresar los datos anteriores a **"data": []**

Este es mi codigo de VB.NET:

```
Dim respuesta = obj.login '' Aca solamente hace la consulta de un login 

If respuesta.HasRows Then

    Session.Timeout = 5
    Dim key = Session.SessionID

    Dim array As New JArray()

    While respuesta.Read
        obj.id = respuesta(0)
        For index As Integer = 0 To respuesta.FieldCount - 1
            array.Add(respuesta(index))
        Next
    End While

    Dim o As New JObject()


    o("Id") = array(0)
    o("NombreUsuario") = array(1)
    o("Clave") = array(2)
    o("CorreoElectronico") = array(3)
    o("Token") = key

    respuesta.Close()

    Dim schema As JSchema = JSchema.Parse(o.ToString)    

    obj.TokenKey = key

    Dim token = obj.token

    If token Then

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        Response.Write(o)
    Else
        print_json("401", "Error de autenticacion", Nothing)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolví mi problema, comparto el código por si acaso cualquiera le pase lo mismo

```
                               Dim respuesta = obj.login                                
                               If respuesta.HasRows Then

                                Session.Timeout = 5
                                Dim key = Session.SessionID

                                Dim array As New JArray()

                                While respuesta.Read
                                    obj.id = respuesta(0)
                                    For index As Integer = 0 To respuesta.FieldCount - 1
                                        array.Add(respuesta(index))
                                    Next
                                End While

                                Dim o As New JObject()



                                o("Id") = array(0)
                                o("NombreUsuario") = array(1)
                                o("Clave") = array(2)
                                o("CorreoElectronico") = array(3)
                                o("Token") = key



                                Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, JObject)

                                dict.Add("data", o)


                                respuesta.Close()




                                obj.TokenKey = key

                                Dim token = obj.token

                                If token Then

                                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

                                    Dim stringb As New StringBuilder

                                    stringb.Append("{")
                                    stringb.Append(Chr(34) & "statusCode" & Chr(34) & ": 200,")
                                    stringb.Append(Chr(34) & "statusText" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "OK" & Chr(34) & ",")


                                    For Each a In dict


                                        stringb.Append(Chr(34) & a.Key.ToString & Chr(34))
                                        stringb.Append(":")
                                        stringb.Append(a.Value.ToString)
                                        stringb.Append("}")

                                    Next

                                    Response.Write(stringb)


                                Else
                                    print_json("401", "Error de autenticacion", Nothing)
                                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string json = @"{
statusCode: 200,
statusText: 'OK',
data: [
        {
            Id: 1,
            NombreUsuario: 'admin',
            Clave: 'admin',
            CorreoElectronico: 'admin@localhost',
            Token: '0m1sand5p2ru5gdinaewi2ox'
        }    
     ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Comment: No creo que sea tan sencillo como eso, puesto a que yo no creo el JSON mediante un String, traigo los datos del SQLDataReader desde la BD y luego los anado al JArray que luego, son agregados a un JObject. Mas Sin embargo, no se preocupen pues ya resolvi mi problema, gracias por la ayuda